# Shared Preferences Not Working in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I have an app that uses sharedpreferences.  It works fine in Activities.  But, the same SharedPreference methods won't work in a BroadcastReceiver or Service.

Example Activity works fine:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SetTelco extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

    public static final String Telco="Telco";
    public static String phoneNum;

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        //parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        String phoneNum = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_short_codes)[parent.getSelectedItemPosition()];
        SharedPreferences telco=getSharedPreferences(Telco,Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor telcoEdit=telco.edit();
        telcoEdit.clear();
        telcoEdit.putString(Telco, phoneNum);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phoneNum, 5000).show();
        telcoEdit.commit();
    }
}
```

=========================

Example BroadcastReceiver:

Eclipse gives me an error:
Multiple markers at this line
    - The field Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated
    - The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type SetAlarms

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SetAlarms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
        SharedPreferences telco=getSharedPreferences(Telco,Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        String phoneNum="Empty";
        phoneNum=telco.getString(Telco,"Empty");
                .
                .
                .
                sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, sendMsg, null, null);
    }
}
```

Can't figure out what the difference is.  According to the docs, SharedPreferences should work in all components, Activities & Services.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSharedPreferences()` is a method on `Context`. You can call it on the `Context` that is passed into your `onReceive()` method.

Comment: telco=context.getSharedPreferences(Telco,Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);